# how to change values of objects?

Tags: python, class, object

I have to create a class in which there  is a function that modifies values of variables in objects.
class dog:

```
class dog:

    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.z=z
    def __str__(self):

       return print("mi nombre es "+self.x)
    def bark(self,otr):
        if self.z*self.y>otr.z*otr.y:
            print("gano: "+self.x)

            int(otr.x)=int(otr.x)-2

        if self.z*self.y<otr.z*otr.y:
            print("gano: "+otr.x)

            int(self.x)=int(self.x)-2
```

but when i try to run it it gives me a "cant assign function to call" error, also i wanted to know if this is the right approach

Comment: Change `int(otr.x)=int(otr.x)-2` by `otr.x=int(otr.x)-2`. The `int(otr.x)` is not needed if you're sure that `otr.x` is an integer.

Comment: Or even simpler: `otr.x -= 2` and `self.x -= 2`.

Answer (score 0):

I have just modified your dog class here. See my modification and comment in your code below:-

```
class dog:
def __init__(self,x,y,z):
    self.x=x
    self.y=y
    self.z=z

def __str__(self):
    return print("mi nombre es "+self.x)    

def bark(self,otr):
    if self.z*self.y>otr.z*otr.y:
        print("gano: "+self.x)
        otr.x = int(otr.x)-2
    if self.z*self.y<otr.z*otr.y:
        print("gano: "+otr.x)
        self.x = int(self.x)-2 #what were you doing by int(self.x) on the left hand site which I removed. Don't do anything randomly. you need to understand what you are doing. For example - int(val) here val will be converted into integer from any value like string, double etc. Hence left hand side it does not mean anything.
```